# Creating an object that is also a type (e.g str !type!)

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Our system asks users to annotate function parameters with certain type annotations:

```py
def some_func(data_path: InputPath('CSV') = None):
```

`InputPath` is a normal class.

```py
class InputPath:
  def __init__(self, type_name):
    sefl.type_name = type_name
```

Everything works fine, but our users complain that linters like mypy show errors because `InputPath('CSV')` is an object, not a type.

What would be the easiest and least hacky way to satisfy mypy? It would be great if it acted as if `issubclass(InputPath('CSV'), str)` (in other cases `issubclass(InputTextFile('CSV'), TextIOWrapper)`).

I could try something like the following, but it looks kind of hacky:

```py
def InputPath(type_name):
  return type(
    'InputPath_' + type_name,
    (str,),
    {'type_name': type_name},
  )
```

Comment: "Our system asks users to annotate function parameters with certain type annotations" this just doesn't make any sense. You are using type annotations for your own purpose, which doesn't seem to be to work with python type annotations as specified by [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). So, why do you want it to be mypy compatible?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using annotations to represent type information here. If you really want to do that, you should either just not use mypy, or use [`typing.no_type_check`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.no_type_check) to indicate that the annotations aren't type hints.

Comment: Note, your `def InputPath` is pointless, if you annotate anything with `InputPath('CSV')` then mypy is going to consider it `Any`, you can't *dynamically* create the types, it's for *static typing*

Comment: I'm not sure python limits the annotations to only types. Also, why can't InputPath be a type? I can say `InputPath = str`. I could define `InputPath = {'CSV': str}` and `InputPath['CSV']` would be a type...

Comment: The problem is: When editing code, users see linter squiggles and warnings. Users do not like squiggles and warnings.

Comment: Pythong has lots of things in typing. e.g. typing.Literal, typing.TypeVar . Python also has metaclasses. I'm pretty sure something can work. Also "impersonating" TextIOWrapper or str would be useful since the IDE users may get autocomplete.

Comment: @Ark-kun *python* doesn't, but if you are using `mypy`, then you are using a static time type checker for type annotations that fulfill the [PEP 484 type annotation specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), which *does* require it to be either a type or a type annotation from `typing` as detailed int the spec... what do metaclasses have to do with anything?

Comment: @Ark-kun well, I don't know what to tell you. You are asking basically how to use mypy for something it isn't built to do. You can create a fork of mypy and modify it to work the way you want, and have your own type system.

Comment: There are three parts: User code, our library, mypy. Are you saying that the problem is not solvable without modifying user code or mypy?

Comment: >"You are asking basically "how do I use mypy without using mypy".". No. I'm asking "How to mypy on user code that uses out object annotations without modifying mypy or user code".

Comment: Whether or not the file system has a CSV somewhere is a matter of file system state, not object type. You're trying to get a static type checker to deal with runtime file system state. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ark-kun "that uses our object annotations" **mypy doesn't do that**, you *are* asking how to get mypy to do something it doesn't do. They didn't write mypy to understand your bespoke annotations. Why do you expect to be able to use `mypy` for that? So yes, what I'm saying is that either you *stick* to what `mypy` is designed to deal with, **as specified in PEP 484 which defines pythons type annotation system** or you modify `mypy` to do something it doesn't currently do *(understand your annotations).

Comment: >"Whether or not the file system has a CSV somewhere is a matter of file system state, not object type" I'm not sure I understand where you got this impression that this has something to do with the state of the filesystem. InputPath("CSV") annotation is semantically same as InputPathForCsv *type*. A type, not an actual path string. And if I have `class InputPathForCsv(str): pass` then `def some_func(data_path: InputPathForCsv = None):` does not trigger mypy errors. More so, mypy actually helps the user by showing error if they try to pass, say, `InputPathForZip` value to `some_func`.